# Initial loading of data to prevent flickering

Tags: angularjs

I create a test for my website in Angular but I am not impressed with the loading speed.

I put all my serverdata into a json object which is then read by the controller, which will then bind everything on the screen.

Meanwhile I use ng-cloak to hide all the not-loaded elements, but it can easily take a second and everything flashes back and forth.

I have been searching for a while but it seems there is no way to load the initial data in the controller through the model, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid the "flickering", couldn't you just wrap your whole page in an `ng-cloak` until your data is ready? Or at least show a loading gif while the data is populated. Seems like a pretty common pattern on single page applications.